# The \cellcolor command of the colortbl package does not work

Tags: tables, color, cell

I'm trying to use the `\cellcolor` command from the `colortbl` package. Here is the code I wrote:

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!hb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{$B_3B_2 \backslash B_1B_0$} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
01 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
11 & \cellcolor{green!25}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_3$}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}
```

When I compile the code, everything works just fine, but the cell is not colored. I have already searched the `colortbl.sty` file and deleted it so it's reinstalled (in case of it's an old version), but nothing changed. The sty file is date 18/12/2018. Does someone know why it's not working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have the `xcolor` package loaded as well?

Comment: I read that colortbl loaded the xcolor package, so no. I just tried to explicitly load the xcolor package (\usepackage{xcolor}), but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Please mention what `LaTeX` engine you are using, e.g., `PDFLaTeX`, `XELaTeX`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `mathenv` causes the error, and I am not sure how it was. May some `experts` will provide the explanation, how it affected the output. And the modified tags are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % utilisé pour les ensembles
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % LaTeX, comprends les accents !
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%pour personnaliser les en-têtes
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{mathenv}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\definecolor{listingcolor}{rgb}{0.6,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{cadre}{rgb}{.1,.1,.8}

\geometry{ hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\newcommand{\euros}{\euro\hspace{0.5em}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{./Images/LOGO_HEPH-CONDORCET.png}}
%\fancyhead[C]{}
%\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{./Images/Condorcet.jpg}}
%\fancyfoot[L]{}
%\fancyfoot[C]{-~\thepage~-}
%\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}% filet en haut de page
\addtolength{\headheight}{0pt} % espace pour le filet
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % pas de filet en bas
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages de têtes de chapitre
\fancyhead{} % supprime l'entete
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % et le filet
}

\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{1.5em}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{230,230,230}

\lstdefinelanguage{CUDA}
{
 language=C,
 deletekeywords={},
 morekeywords = {__global__, blockIdx, threadIdx, cudaMemcpy, cudaFree, void, float, const, unsigned, uint, char, bool},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{CCustom}
{
 language=C,
 deletekeywords={},
 morekeywords = {parallel, omp, atomic, critical, master, num_threads, nowait, section, sections, task, single, private, barrier, firstprivate, lastprivate, reduction, shared, schedule, dynamic, guided, ordered, pragma, (incr), \#},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{VB}
{
 language=VBScript,
 deletekeywords={Add},
 morekeywords = {As, ByVal, ByRef, New, AddressOf, Public, Sub, Dim, Function, Private, End, Const,With, Protected, Overrides, Of, Me, Nothing, True, False, AndAlso, Overloads, TryCast, IsNot, Object, In, Throw},
}

\lstset%
{%
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{cadre}\small,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    escapeinside={^*}{*^},
    emph={},
    emphstyle=\color{blue},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=trbl,
    framesep=14pt,
    framerule=1pt,
    rulecolor = \color{cadre},
    showstringspaces=false,
    language = CCustom,
    backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray},
}

\newcommand{\Xor}[3]{
\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{lr}
& #1 \\
\oplus & #2 \\
\hline
& #3
\end{array}$
\end{center}
}


\headheight=24pt

%XLOP

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rappels}

\section{Code de Gray}

\subsection{Introduction}

Le \textbf{code de Gray}, également appelé code Gray ou \textbf{code binaire réfléchi}, est un type de codage binaire permettant de ne modifier qu'un seul bit à la fois quand un nombre est augmenté d'une unité. Soit un nombre $N$ en binaire pur, pour obtenir son équivalent $n$ en binaire réfléchi, il suffit de calculer le OU exclusif entre le binaire de départ, $N$, et ce même binaire décalé d'un rang à droite (le dernier bit est supprimé). Prenons par exemple le nombre 5. Celui-ci s'écrit en binaire $0101$. Pour trouver son équivalent en code de Gray, il faut donc effectuer un OU exclusif entre $0101$ et $010$ :

\Xor{0101}{010}{0111}

Le chiffre 5 s'écrit donc en code Gray $0111$.

\subsection{Convertisseur de de code binaire en code Gray}

La construction du code Gray pour les nombres de 0 à 15 est représentée par le tableau suivant :

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc|cccc}
Nombre & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Code binaire pur} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Code Gray} \\
décimal & \mbox{$B_3$} & \mbox{$B_2$} & \mbox{$B_1$} & \mbox{$B_0$} & \mbox{$G_3$} & \mbox{$G_2$} & \mbox{$G_1$} & \mbox{$G_0$} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
7 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
9 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
10 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
11 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
12 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
13 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
14 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
15 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{footnotesize}

\textbf{Exercice} : établissons un diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_0$, $G_1$, $G_2$ et $G_3$ à partir de $B_0$, $B_1$, $B_2$ et $B_3$.

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!hb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{$B_3B_2 \backslash B_1B_0$} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
01 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
11 & \cellcolor{green!25}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_3$}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!hb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{$B_3B_2 \backslash B_1B_0$} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
01 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
11 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_2$}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!hb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{$B_3B_2 \backslash B_1B_0$} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
00 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
01 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
11 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_1$}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!hb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{$B_3B_2 \backslash B_1B_0$} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
00 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
01 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
11 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
10 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagramme de Karnaugh pour $G_0$}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}

\newpage

\textbf{Exercice} : nous pouvons maintenant établir les équations de $G_0$ à $G_3$ :
\begin{math}
G_0 = B_1B_0+
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: It works !! Thanks a lot ! That was a tricky problem !